# Firefox 53 Asking to Restart to Update Endlessly

Tags: mac, firefox

I've run into an odd issue with Firefox, and I'm not sure where else to go. Mozilla's own support pages on the issue don't even load either.

The issue started with the update to Firefox 53. Once it completed, the dialog box to Reboot to install 53 popped up. If I click "Restart Now", it does so, and once the program launches again, the same dialog pops up, over and over.

[image]

The dialog looks like this, except it's for Firefox 53.

I have tried Resetting Firefox to its default state. I have also completely uninstalled the program by deleting it from Applications, and then reinstalled with a clean download from Safari. Neither of these options have helped.

Is there something I've missed here? It's more of an annoyance than anything, the dialog doesn't do any harm, but I'd like to figure out why it's happening on a clean install too.

Comment: The "tech support" in me compels me to ask, have you tried rebooting the entire computer yet (not just the firefox program) to see if the issue persists afterward?

Comment: @TopHat Indeed I have, the behavior persists.

Comment: I figured that'd probably be the case, but I couldn't help asking. :b Could you add a screenshot of the pop-up?

Comment: @TopHat Done. The screenshot is from somewhere else, as the machine I'm having this problem on is remote and offline at the moment. It's for Firefox 53 as well, not 52.0.2.

Comment: I've collected the following output from a mac with the same version of Firefox that is not having this problem. I'd like you to provide this output (if you can) so that I can compare: `ls -lahR ~/Library/Application\ Support/Firefox/` It's going to be a lot of output so you'll probably want to put it in something like pastebin.com and link to it.

Comment: @TopHat Mozilla's support threads are back up, and I found a solution that worked for me. I can still try to get this output if you'd like, but the issue has been resolved on my end. Thank you for your help though!

Comment: Nah, don't worry about it. I'm glad you found your solution! :)

Comment: Why does this problem occur on many different software? I get the updates available message for Java Runtime Environment 3 or 4 times everyday since installing it. With other programs as well. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firefox's own support pages are finally back online after their migration to Moz://a.
[This link](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1157427) explains my issue and offers the correct solution, which is as follows:

- Delete the folder "Mozilla" residing in `/Users/<user>/Library/Caches/`
- Restart Firefox.

The dialog should no longer pop up each time the program is launched.

Comment: Potential editors, please note that **Moz://a** is not a typo or spelling error.  It is the proper nomenclature, exactly as the author intended:  [https://blog.mozilla.org/opendesign/arrival/](https://blog.mozilla.org/opendesign/arrival/)